# Is it possible in Python to stop the program after a certain time while constantly waiting for input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've truly searched the web but couldn't find an answer so i am here. The thing i need is something different but this is the simplified version of my problem:

Random number is generated and player is guessing with a while loop, if s/he cant find the result in x sec, game terminates or while loop breakes.

I've tried threading, timer and so on. No hope, can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: Just set the start time and in the while loop before asking the user's input get the time difference with the start time. If it's over the limit, break out.

Comment: @Bramvanroy i already did it but its not the exact thing i need. User learnes time has finished if he tries to input. I want player to not be able to input if time has reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use threading is right way to do this. You maybe struggling with `sys.exit()` which just kills the thread and not the whole script when it's called inside a thread. Try `os._exit(0)` instead.

```
import threading
import time
import os

def wait():
    time.sleep (10)
    os._exit (0)


threading.Thread (target=wait).start()

while True:
    print ('guess number')
    input()

    # rest of the programm
```

Comment: os._exit(0) solved my issue for sure! I didn't know what to look but thanks!

Comment: Thank you again for recognizing that i am newbie. I try my best to fit, CS junior. Getting better each day! Have a nice day sir!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want to limit the end user for guessing the number, may be you can put a check on number of tries inside your loop.
Alternatively you can use python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) library firstly outside the while loop to get the current time and then inside the loop and take the difference of both timestamp. This will give you **X**.